# Betti numbers and cycles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am a physicist trying to have a better understanding of cycles for CY manifolds. From what I read, I am tempted to do the following conclusion: for any complex manifold $M$ of real dimension $n$,
\begin{equation}
    b_p = \dim H^p_{\text{dR}}(M) = \dim H^{n-p}_{\text{dR}}(M) = \dim H_p(M)
\end{equation}
so the Betti number $b_p$ directly gives the number of independant $p$-cycles of $M$. Is that true ?

Comment: The equalities you state are true provided $M$ is also closed (this is needed for the middle equality).